# Import data from one sheet to another with multiple function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, formula, import-from-excel

I need help. Is it possible to import a data from one sheet to another but the data I'm trying to import should be substracted from a tab of the original sheet?
The formula should look like this:

```
=(importrange("https://LINKHERE","JAN!j18")).
```

Now the data on `J18` is what I'm trying to import but it is being added from `Jan!j18`. I'm trying to put this to `Feb!j18` (but wants to exclude the added data from `Jan!18`. It was added intentionally to feb but the other sheet needs a monthly numbers only. Any help please?

Comment: Welcome! Please see stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and edit your question to show us what you tried after researching it, and what went wrong so that others can help troubleshoot a minimum reproducible example stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't quite follow your problem.

But if you import a range into an array, you can then loop through it and manipulate it

```
Sub test1()

arr1 = Range(Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1), Worksheets(1).Cells(4, 3))

'Note, that the array will start at 1, rather than 0.
For iRow = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
    For iCol = 1 To UBound(arr1, 2)
        'Which is convenient as we're pasting back to a workbook
        Worksheets(2).Cells(iRow, iCol) = arr1(iRow, iCol) + 10
    Next iCol
Next iRow
End Sub
```

Do pay attention to the array indices - as going to and from ranges & workbooks is abnormal relative to usual array use